# How to Resolve duplicate entry: com/google/gson/JsonParseException.class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

I am using `android studio 3.0`,no matter what i do i can't generate or build `APK` astonishingly it runs on `emulator` but build fails on real android device.

[image]

This is how the error appears when i try to build `APK`.

It actually works on other computers only on this system there is this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude  module: 'gson'
}
```

Comment: Because i cant exclude it of i need it in other areas of my project.

Comment: Maybe there is the gson and the jackson libraries in your project or different gson versions. You can execute _./gradlew app:dependencies_ in the Terminal tab and check the possible cause of this duplicity.

Answer (score 0):

You must not have repeated library in your app or your dependence program
try this

```
android {
    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    } 
}
```

Comment: Not working....Update: it actually works on other computers only on this system there is this issue.